# Putting a one-page view of my website on other websites I do

Tags: website-design, layout, design-patterns, user-behavior

When I do websites, most times I add a page dedicated only to my main website to serve as publicity and awareness..this is normally done after seeking the consent of the website owner.

The issues I'm having are as follows :

1) Will it be okay to align my one-page website on other websites, with the color scheme of the websites I put them ? The feeling I have is to make users aware that..yes they are still on the website but the page they are viewing now is a different product.

2) Does this have to be the same color scheme and layout as my actual website (Not available at this moment).

3) How does this affect the UX of visitors if any.

4) Is there a way to better do this if any.

Comment: A referral from your client is far more valuable then self promoting on his site. A back link in the footer to provide proof you did the work is enough for anyone who cares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a general practice, it is always wise to link the client website to own website rather than having a dedicated page there.

Having a dedicated page will always break the way the client website looks and how the visitor perceives the date given from that dedicated page. Rather have a nice logo somewhere saying DEVELOPMENT PARTNER and then link the same to the mail website. That way they know that the site which opens is of a different identity and they understand what they are looking at.

Also, if still you want a dedicated page, then its better to open a small modal with some info about your company and then link it to you mail website. That way, the parent website branding will not be affected and the information will also be passed as you need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. Please explain what you mean by open modal..

Comment: What is meant was modal windows... rather a overlay over the existing page. It can have some info and a link to your site